# Abnormal behavior of function in Singly Linked list program

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list, function-definition

Few days back I made a Singly Linked list Implementation Program using C with operations - insertion at front, insertion at back , deletion at back , deletion at front and display which was working fine.

Yesterday I made another program to insert a node at certain position in singly linked list adding extra function - insertion at position , and rest functions were copied from previous code which were working fine in previous program. Now when I was performing operations on old functions in new programs which were working fine in old program , they were showing abnormal behaviour.

Note:

**I am getting error in old functions not new function.**

**Old Program is Running Fine**

[image]

Error: when I am using inserting two or more values in linked list using either of function - insertion at front or insertion at back and then using display function. Infinite loop is running

```
//Program Which was working fine
//Linked List Implementation
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *link;
}node;
void add_front(node **head)
{
    int value;
    
    if((*head) == NULL)
    {
        *head = malloc(sizeof(node));
        printf("Enter the value to insert : ");
        scanf("%d",&value);
        (*head)->data = value;
        (*head)->link = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        node *temp;
        temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
        printf("Enter the value to insert : ");
        scanf("%d",&value);
        temp->data = value;
        temp->link = *head;
        *head = temp;
        free(temp);
    }
}
void add_end(node **head)
{
    int value;
    if((*head) == NULL)
    {
        *head = malloc(sizeof(node));
        printf("Enter the value to insert : ");
        scanf("%d",&value);
        (*head)->data = value;
        (*head)->link = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        node * temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
        node * ptr = *head;
        printf("Enter the value to insert : ");
        scanf("%d",&value);
        temp->data = value;
        temp->link = NULL;
        while(ptr->link != NULL)
        {
            ptr = ptr->link;
        }
        ptr->link = temp;
        free(temp);
        free(ptr);
    }
}
void del_front(node **head)
{
    if((*head) != NULL)
    {
        node *temp;
        temp = *head;
        printf("Value of deleted node is %d \n",(*head)->data);
        *head = (*head)->link;
        free(temp);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Linked list is Empty...\n");
    }
}
node *del_end(node *head)
{
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("Linked List is Empty...\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    else if (head->link == NULL)
    {
        printf("Value of deleted node is %d\n",head->data);
        free(head);
        head = NULL;
        return head;
    }
    else
    {
        node * ptr1 = head;
        node * ptr2 = NULL;
        while(ptr1->link != NULL)
        {
            ptr2 = ptr1;
            ptr1 = ptr1->link;
        }
        printf("Value of deleted node is %d\n",ptr1->data);
        free(ptr2->link);
        ptr2->link = NULL;
        return head;
        free(ptr1);
        free(ptr2);
    }
}
void display(node *head)
{
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("Linked List is Empty...\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while(head != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d   ",head->data);
            head = head->link;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int main()
{
    node *head = NULL;
    int choice;
    printf("Linked list Implementation...\n\n");

    printf("Enter \n1. To add next node at beginning of the linked list\n");
    printf("2. To add next node at end of the linked list\n");
    printf("3. To delete first node\n");
    printf("4. To delete last node\n");
    printf("5. To display the linked list\n");
    printf("6.Exit\n");

    do
    {
        printf("Enter your choice: \n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                add_front(&head);
                break;
            case 2:
                add_end(&head);
                break;
            case 3:
                del_front(&head);
                break;
            case 4:
                head = del_end(head);
                break;
            case 5:
                display(head);
                break;
            case 6:
                printf("Exiting...\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Wrong Choice...\n");
        }
    }while(choice!=6);
    free(head);
    return 0;
}
```

```
//program having error
// inserting a node at a given position in singly linked list 
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *link;
}node;
void add_front(node **head)
{
    int value;
    
    if((*head) == NULL)
    {
        *head = malloc(sizeof(node));
        printf("Enter the value to insert : ");
        scanf("%d",&value);
        (*head)->data = value;
        (*head)->link = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        node *temp;
        temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
        printf("Enter the value to insert : ");
        scanf("%d",&value);
        temp->data = value;
        temp->link = *head;
        *head = temp;
        free(temp);
    }
}
void add_end(node **head)
{
    int value;
    if((*head) == NULL)
    {
        *head = malloc(sizeof(node));
        printf("Enter the value to insert : ");
        scanf("%d",&value);
        (*head)->data = value;
        (*head)->link = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        node * temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
        node * ptr = *head;
        printf("Enter the value to insert : ");
        scanf("%d",&value);
        temp->data = value;
        temp->link = NULL;
        while(ptr->link != NULL)
        {
            ptr = ptr->link;
        }
        ptr->link = temp;
        free(temp);
        free(ptr);
    }
}
void del_front(node **head)
{
    if((*head) != NULL)
    {
        node *temp;
        temp = *head;
        printf("Value of deleted node is %d \n",(*head)->data);
        *head = (*head)->link;
        free(temp);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Linked list is Empty...\n");
    }
}
node *del_end(node *head)
{
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("Linked List is Empty...\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    else if (head->link == NULL)
    {
        printf("Value of deleted node is %d\n",head->data);
        free(head);
        head = NULL;
        return head;
    }
    else
    {
        node * ptr1 = head;
        node * ptr2 = NULL;
        while(ptr1->link != NULL)
        {
            ptr2 = ptr1;
            ptr1 = ptr1->link;
        }
        printf("Value of deleted node is %d\n",ptr1->data);
        free(ptr2->link);
        ptr2->link = NULL;
        return head;
        free(ptr1);
        free(ptr2);
    }
}
node *insert_pos(node *head)
{
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("Linked List is Empty...\n");
        return;
    }
    int pos;
    node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    printf("Enter the position to insert new node : ");
    scanf("%d",&pos);
    if(pos == 1)
    {
        printf("Enter the value to insert : ");
        scanf("%d",&(temp->data));
        temp->link = head;
        head = temp;
        return head;
    }
    int n = 1; 
    while(pos!=2)
    {
        if(head->link == NULL)
        {
            printf("Linked List has only %d node\n",n);
            return;
        }
        head = head->link;
        n++;
        pos--;
    }
    node *ptr = malloc(sizeof(node));
    ptr = head->link;
    printf("Enter the value to insert : ");
    scanf("%d",&(temp->data));
    head->link = temp;
    temp->link = ptr;
    free(ptr);
}
node *delete_pos(node *head)
{
    return;
}
void display(node *head)
{
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("Linked List is Empty...\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while(head != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d   ",head->data);
            head = head->link;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int main()
{
    node *head = NULL;
    int choice;
    printf("Linked list Implementation...\n\n");
    printf("Enter \n1. To add next node at beginning of the linked list\n");
    printf("2. To add next node at end of the linked list\n");
    printf("3. To delete first node\n");
    printf("4. To delete last node\n");
    printf("5. To insert a node at certain position\n");
    printf("6. To delete a node at certain position\n");
    printf("7. To display the linked list\n");
    printf("8.Exit\n");

    do
    {
        printf("Enter your choice: \n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                add_front(&head);
                break;
            case 2:
                add_end(&head);
                break;
            case 3:
                del_front(&head);
                break;
            case 4:
                head = del_end(head);
                break;
            case 5:
                head = insert_pos(head);
                break;
            case 6:
                delete_pos(head);
                break;
            case 7:
                display(head);
                break;
            case 8:
                printf("Exiting...\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Wrong Choice...\n");
        }
    }while(choice!=8);
    free(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [mre], with emphasis on the ***minimal*** part. LAstly please learn how to [edit] your question to improve it, not only by showing a *minimal* example but also telling us what efforts at debugging your program you have made.

Answer (score 0):

There is already undefined behavior in the first function `add_front` in this code snippet

```
else
{
    node *temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    printf("Enter the value to insert : ");
    scanf("%d",&value);
    temp->data = value;
    temp->link = *head;
    *head = temp;
    free(temp);
    ^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

You deleted the node that was added in the list.

And the function `add_front` has duplicated code.

The same problem exist with the function `add_end` In this function you decided to delete even two valid nodes.:)

```
else
{
    node * temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    node * ptr = *head;
    printf("Enter the value to insert : ");
    scanf("%d",&value);
    temp->data = value;
    temp->link = NULL;
    while(ptr->link != NULL)
    {
        ptr = ptr->link;
    }
    ptr->link = temp;
    free(temp);
    ^^^^^^^^^^
    free(ptr);
    ^^^^^^^^^
}
```

You shall not delete nodes in these functions.

In the function del_end the code after the return statement never gets the control and must be removed.

```
    printf("Value of deleted node is %d\n",ptr1->data);
    free(ptr2->link);
    ptr2->link = NULL;
    return head;
    free(ptr1);   // <===
    free(ptr2);   // <===
```

If you want to add and delete nodes at the end of the list then you should declare a tw-sided singly-linked list.